# Angular Remove service worker for a page url

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have an angular application with a service worker registered. I want to remove the service worker for `account/checkout` route.

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/manifest.webmanifest", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**", "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with this below code,

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/index.html",
                    "/manifest.webmanifest",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "navigationUrls": [
        "!/account/checkout"
    ]
}
```

For more reference please refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#navigationurls) link.